# Divisibility Induction

Tags: number-theory, induction, divisibility

Hey guys had a induction problem for hw and was having trouble with it. I tried mods and a/b where a and b are integers but cant seem to prove the last step.

[image]

Comment: I’d use induction (on $n$) to show that $a\equiv b\pmod m$ implies $a^n\equiv b^n\pmod m$. Then apply with $a=2,b=-1,m=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\;2^{n+1}+(-1)^n=2^{n+1}-(-1)^{n+1}\,$, then remember the identity $\,a^k-b^k=(a-b)(\cdots)\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] For an alternative proof by induction, note that:

$$2^{n+1}+(-1)^n= 2 \cdot \left(2^n \color{blue}{+ (-1)^{n-1}}\right) \color{blue}{- 2 \cdot (-1)^{n-1}} + (-1)^n = 2 \cdot \left(2^n + (-1)^{n-1}\right) + 3 \cdot (-1)^n$$

Comment: I was having trouble with the n = k + 1 step where 2^k+2 + (-1)^k+1 has to be divisible by 3

Comment: @JeffreyChiu Are you *required* to use induction? The direct proof (above) is a lot simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use induction